# How to retrieve values of attributes in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to compare the string in my linked list to a string in a new node so i can compare them alphabetically. My compiler expected a primary expression before '->'. How can i use the values in my linked list as variables and compare strings?

```
struct element {
        std::string woord;
        struct element * next = NULL;
};
void VoegToeAlfabetisch(element** lijst, std::string tekst)
{
    element* x(new element); 
    x->woord = tekst; 
    while (*lijst != NULL) {
        std::string print = element->woord;
    }
}
int main()
{
    element* root = NULL;
    VoegToeAlfabetisch(&root, "Alfabetisch");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a good look at this line: `std::string print = element->woord;`

Comment: That's how I retrieve the value of a string in my node right?

Comment: As the answer states, you want an instance of `element` (technically, in your case, a pointer to an instance of it but still), `element` itself is just a type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you mean

```
std::string print = (*lisjt)-> word
```

element is the name of a type not a variable. This code has an infinite loop in it, but I assume you will fix that once you get it to compile

Also, please post the exact error message and comment the line it points to in any question you post with compiler errors.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, why does it loop? The last pointer of my linked list (*lijst) is NULL right?

Comment: Good reason to capitalize Types and leave variables lowercase. Or at least use some consistant style that makes sense.

Comment: @Woask: `*lisjt` is not being modified, so it will never be `NULL`.

Comment: `while (*lijst != NULL)`. You never change lijst in the loop. So either it never loops or it loops forever

Comment: I think I fixed it with the following code:
    while (*lijst != NULL) {
std::string print = (*lijst)->woord;
lijst = &((*lijst)->next);
std::cout << print << std::endl;
    }
Thank you very much for your contribution guys, I really appreciate it!